# Почему при запуске VirtualBox перестает работать bluetooth на наушниках и пропадает звук?

Tags: virtualbox, bluetooth, vagrant

Каждый раз при запуске virtualBox перестают работать наушники через блютуз. Блютуз подключен через USB. USB в виртуальной машине отключен. Впрочем, Коннект пропадает ещё до запуска виртуальной машины - сразу после запуска virtualBox. Помимо наушников по блютуз подключена клавиатура и мышка, но с ними коннект не пропадает. В чем может быть причина и куда рыть?

Comment: Опции вывода звука из виртуальной машины на аудиоустройство которое появляется при подключении ушей?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, подскажите, где смотреть? Повторю, что коннект пропадает как только я вообще запускаю virtualBox.

Comment: Совсем уж по-честному USB-устройство не пошарить, поэтому причины могут быть какие угодно. Если причина в BT драйверах или железке, то можно попробовать BT контроллер на чипе другого производителя. Если наушники не для общения, а для музыки, то можно их из виртуальной машины слушать. На Линуксе можно совсем не пускать VirtualBox к USB.

Comment: судя по западным формумам проблема связана с конкретным устройством блютуз адаптера